# Moving the derivative inside the integral in Schrodinger equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, quantum-mechanics

In the proof that the Schrodinger equation stay normalized as time goes on, it starts with moving the time derivative inside the integral, i.e.
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,t)|^2dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx.$$

How is the swapping of the derivative and integral justified here? Is this mathematically justifiable or just something we assume holds in physics?

Comment: They are both linear operators on the space of functions (assuming some things about convergence). To make this rigorous, you would have to check convergence. But in general this is perfectly okay.